# $\overline A$ is the set of limits of convergent nets with values in $A$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, nets

In proving that the equivalence between different definitions of continuous functions between topological spaces, I come across this lemma. Could you have a check if my attempt is correct?

> *Lemma:* Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Then $\overline A$ is the set of limits of convergent nets with values in $A$.

**Proof:** For $x \in X$, let $\mathcal N_x$ be the set of all neighborhoods of $x$. We have $$\overline A = \{x \in X \mid \forall U \in \mathcal N_x: U \cap A \neq \emptyset \}.$$

Then we define a pre-order $\le$ on $\mathcal N_x$ by $U_1 \le U_2 \iff U_2 \subseteq U_1$. Then $\mathcal N_x$ is a directed set. Let $x \in \overline A$. By axiom of choice, for each $U \in \mathcal N_x$, there is $x_U \in U \cap A$. Hence $(x_U)_{U \in \mathcal N_x}$ is a net in $A$ such that $x_U \to x$. Conversely, let $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ be a net in $A$ that converges to $x \in X$. For each $U \in \mathcal N_x$, there is $d' \in D$ such that $x_d \in U$ for all $d \ge d'$. This means $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for all $U \in \mathcal N_x$. Hence $x \in \overline A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good for mentioning the rôle of AC. Explain *why* $\mathcal N_x$ is directed under $\le$ (yes, intersection of neighbourhoods ...). Add also the argument **why** $(x_U)_{U \in \mathcal N_x}$  converges to $x$ (it's a minor thing but shows why we have to define the pre-order the way we do). It depends on the intended audience, I suppose, but in home work or self-study fill in all the details...

The reverse direction I have no quarrel with, as remarking that $x_{d'} \in A \cap U$ to *witness* the non-emptyness, might be *too* trivial? I'll let it pass...

Ideas are fine.