# Initial Topology and Weak and Strong Operator Topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Given a set $X$ and a family of topological spaces $(Y_i)_{i \in I}$ and functions $f_i : X \to Y_i$, we can define a topology on $X$ called the initial topology on $X$ with respect to the topological spaces and functions $(Y_i, f_i)_{i \in I}$. This topology is defined to be the coarsest/weakest/smallest topology with respect to which all the maps $f_i$ are continuous. In terms of open sets, all sets of the form $f_i^{-1}(U)$ for $U$ open in $Y_i$ and some $i \in I$ forms a subbasis of this (the initial) topology on $X$. Also, a net $(x_j) \subseteq X$ converges to $x \in X$ with respect to this topology if and only if $f_i(x_j) \to f_i(x)$ in $Y_i$ for every $i \in I$.

Using this procedure, we can define the weak and strong operator topology on $B(\mathcal{H})$, the $C^*$-algebra of all bounded linear operators on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, via certain families of seminorms. According to the book [An introduction to $II_1$ factors](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epopa/Books/IIun.pdf), the weak operator topology is the initial topology generated by the seminorms $p_{\xi , \eta}(x) := |\langle \xi , x \eta \rangle |$ for all $\xi , \eta \in \mathcal{H}$, while the strong operator topology is the initial topology generated by the seminorms $p_{\xi}(x) = \|x \xi\|$ for all $\xi \in \mathcal{H}$. Hence, $(x_i)_{i \in I} \subseteq B(\mathcal{H})$ converges to $x \in B(\mathcal{H})$ with respect to the weak topology if and only if $|\langle \xi , x_i \eta \rangle | \to |\langle \xi , x \eta \rangle |$ for every $\xi , \eta \in \mathcal{H}$, while it converges with respect to the strong operator topology if and only if $\|x_i \xi\| \to \|x \xi\|$ for every $\xi \in \mathcal{H}$.

However, in many other sources (wiki, Conway's book on functional analysis, etc.), the weak and strong operator topology seem to be defined slightly different. According to these other sources, $x_i \to x$ in the weak operator topology if and only if $\langle \xi , x_i \eta \rangle \to \langle \xi , x \eta \rangle$ for all $\xi ,\eta \in \mathcal{H}$, while $x_i \to x$ in the strong operator topology if and only if $\|(x_i - x) \xi \| \to 0$ for all $\xi \in \mathcal{H}$. This is slightly different from what I wrote above. Perhaps I am being dumb, but I don't quite see the equivalence between the way the weak and strong operator topology are defined in...compared to other sources.

If $\langle \xi , x_i \eta \rangle \to \langle \xi , x \eta \rangle$, then, because the absolute value function is continuous, we have that $|\langle \xi , x_i \eta \rangle| \to | \langle \xi , x \eta \rangle |$, but I don't see how the converse holds. Again, if $\|(x_i - x) \xi \| \to 0$, then, using the reverse triangle inequality, we have

$$|~ \|x_i \xi \| - \|x \xi \| ~ | \le \|x_i \xi - x \xi \| = \|(x_i -x) \xi \| \to 0$$

But I don't see why the converse holds.

Comment: The part in the 2nd paragraph starting with Hence is incorrect - it misapplies the definition of topology on a vector space by seminorms.  The 3rd paragraph is correct.

Comment: To be more precise, the claim "the weak operator topology is the initial topology generated by the seminorms" is incorrect (and it's not made in the book). Rather, the weak operator topology is initial among all *linear* topologies that make these seminorms continuous.

Comment: @MaoWao You are right; Popa does not explicitly define it as the initial topology. I forgot that I was using this paper http://andreghenriques.com/Seminars/vNAlgSeminarNotes1.pdf to try to make sense of what Popa is saying, where the author of the linked paper does seem to suggest that the weak and strong operator topologies are initial topologies generated by families of seminorms. Hence my confusion.

Comment: Again, I don't see a claim that the weak (or strong) operator topology would be an initial topology in the sense of your first paragraph. It is even explained what the topology generated by a family of seminorms is, and it is not initial for all topologies making the seminorms continuous.

Comment: @MaoWao This is the definition of initial topology I am using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology Specifically, see the section "Definition in terms of open sets". Isn't that what Egbert Rijke is doing in the linked article?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there are many equivalent characterizations of the strong and the weak operator topology. Following Chapter 2.1.4 / Proposition 2.1.20 of [my PhD thesis](https://doi.org/10.14459/2020md1559809) (arXiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.03496)) --- and recalling that the initial topology [is defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) the smallest topology such that all maps from a specified family are continuous --- the following holds (your setting is recovered via $X=Y=\mathcal H$):

> **Proposition.** Let normed spaces $X,Y$ and a topology $\tau$ on $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ be given. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\tau$ is the initial topology on $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ with respect to the family $\{T\mapsto \|Tx-Sx\|\}_{x\in X,S\in\mathcal B(X,Y)}$. We say that $\tau$ is the topology *induced by the seminorms $T\mapsto \|Tx\|$*.
> 2. $\tau$ is the initial topology with respect to the family $\{T\mapsto Tx\}_{x\in X}$.
> 3. For all nets $(T_i)_{i\in I}$ in $ \mathcal B(X,Y)$ and all $T\in \mathcal B(X,Y)$ one has $T_i\to T$ in $\tau$ if and only if $T_ix\to Tx$ for all $x\in X$.
> 4. $\tau$ is the topology generated by the basis $$\mathsf S:=\{N(T,A,\varepsilon)\,:\,T\in\mathcal B(X,Y),A\subset X\text{ finite, }\varepsilon>0\}$$ where $N(T,A,\varepsilon):= \{S\in\mathcal B(X,Y)\,:\,\|Tx-Sx\|<\varepsilon\text{ for all }x\in A\}$, that is, $\tau$ is the collection of arbitrary unions of elements of $\mathsf S$.
>
> If $\tau$ satisfies one (and thus all) these conditions we call it the *strong operator topology.* Moreover, $\tau$ in general is *not* the initial topology with respect to the family $\{T\mapsto\|Tx\|\}_{x\in X}$.

For the weak operator topology one gets an analogous result & proof which I, however, will omit for now (if you're interested you can find all the details in the document I linked).

Either way the proof of this becomes quite simple upon learning that comparing topologies can be done, equivalently, via [nets/generalized sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Definitions):

> Given two topologies $\tau_1,\tau_2$ on an arbitrary set $X$ the following are equivalent:
>
> - $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$ (i.e. $\tau_1$ is weaker than $\tau_2$)
> - ${\rm id}_X:(X,\tau_2)\to(X,\tau_1)$ is continuous ([definition of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces))
> - For every net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ in $X$ which converges to $x\in X$ with respect to $\tau_2$ one has $x_i\to x$ with respect to $\tau_1$. ([characterization of continuity via nets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348575/f-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-fx-d-to-fx-where-x-d-d-in-d-is-a?rq=1), cf. also Theorem 11.8 in *"General Topology"* (1970) by Willard)
>
> In particular, given a set $X$ and a family $\mathcal F:=(f_j)_{j\in J}$ of functions $f_j:X\to Y_j$ (each $Y_j$ being a topological space) a net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ in $X$ converges to $x\in X$ in the initial topology w.r.t. $\mathcal F$ iff $f_j(x_i)\to f_j(X)$ for all $j\in J$ (cf. Theorem 8.10 in Willard's *"General Topology"*)

With this let us come to the

*Proof idea (of the above proposition).* First note that by  "(2) $\Leftrightarrow$ (3)" is precisely the characterization of the initial topology in terms of nets given above.
Then "(1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (3)" boils down to two inequalities, one of which you have stated already (the [reverse triangle inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reverse_Triangle_Inequality/Normed_Vector_Space)):

- If $T_ix\to Tx$, i.e. $\|T_ix-Tx\|\to 0$, then for all $S,x$
  $$
  \big|\|T_ix-Sx\|-\|Tx-Sx\|\big|\leq\|T_ix-Sx-Tx+Sx\|=\|T_ix-Tx\|\to 0
  $$
- If $\|T_ix-Sx\|\to 0$ for all $x,S$, then setting $S=T$ yields $\|T_ix-Tx\|\to 0$, i.e. $T_ix\to Tx$. This is also where your observation comes in that it is not enough to know that $\|T_ix\|\to\|Tx\|$ in order to deduce that $\|T_ix-Tx\|\to 0$. In other words the initial topology with respect to $T\mapsto \|Tx\|$ is, in general, **not** a characterization of the strong operator topology

(4) $\Rightarrow$ (3): This follows from a characterization of a topology in terms of a [basis of the topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)). More precisely, a net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ converges to $x$ if and only if for all basis elements $B$ there exists $i_0\in I$ such that $x_i\in B$ for all $i\succeq i_0$. From this it is straightforward to relate (3) and (4).